# Showing Django model field in HTML

Tags: django, class, models, field

I was wondering how to display a field that I have into an HTML output.

I have this class in my model.py

```
class Tower(models.Model):
    ap = models.IntegerField()
```

And I wanted to display the value ap holds into an HTML output and this is what I have so far in the html document.

```
{% for a in tower.tower_set.all %}
AP: {{a.ap}}<br>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : `tower.tower_set.all` is meaningless. That's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you also have a view like:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from models import Tower

def tower_list(request):
  return TemplateResponse(request, "your_template.html",
                          {"towers": tower.objects.all()})
```

and your template "your_template.html" should look like this:

```
{% for a in towers %}
  AP: {{a.ap}}<br>
{%endfor%}
```